# RSS - displaying image, instead of enclosure?

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I have made a rss feed for my website, but right now the feed is not really displaying a image but just a link to the image as a enclosure. I would like to know what changes I need to make so I can actually display a image in the rss feed.

```
echo '  
   <item>  
      <title>'.html_entity_decode($gag[story], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8").' - '.$thesitename.'</title>  
      <description><![CDATA['.html_entity_decode($gag[story], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8").']]></description>  
      <link>'.$thebaseurl.'/post/'.$gag[PID].'</link>  
      <guid>'.$thebaseurl.'/post/'.$gag[PID].'/</guid>';
      if($gag[pic] != ""){echo '
      <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="'.$thebaseurl.'/pdata/t/'.$gag[pic].'" length="1" />';


      }
echo  '
```

Comment: You have a length of "1". This needs to be the byte size of the image.

Comment: are you saying that the length has to specify the specific byte of the image to be able to display it or do I just set it to a higher value?

Comment: According to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure - yes. There is an alternative however. You can embed an image (using standard HTML) in a `<![CDATA[` tag within the `<description>` if you like. You could always try removing the `length` attribute too. Much better than including something wrong (like 1 or too high a value).